# Formula for the relationship between magnetic field and temperature

Tags: magnetic-fields, temperature

Is there a formula with a relationship between magnetic field and temperature? I am writing a research paper for an assignment and need the formula to showcase the relationship between the magnetic field of a permanent magnet(neodymium) and temperature.

As the temperature increases the magnetic field decreases but is there a formula showing the relationship?

I've looked in

V=IR (ohms law)

Magnetic force

[image]

Drift Velocity

[image]

Temperature and resistance

[image]

Curies Formula

[image]

I've tried to derive formulas to showcase the relationship but no luck so far.

I belive the relationship should be similar to
this [image]

This is the result i got from my experiment
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try Ising model and other variations to describe the magnetic field and thermodinamics in ferromagnetic materials